# Two related number sequences; 20,12,14,8,7 and 4,1,5,9,11

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

Can you predict the next numbers in these two sequences, which are strongly related to each other.

> 20,12,14,8,7

and

> 4,1,5,9,11

these number sequences do not appear in [oeis.org](https://oeis.org)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next number in the first sequence is

> 3

Reasoning

> Beginning at 20, and moving anti-clockwise, these are the numbers of the black/red segments of a standard [dartboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darts#Dartboard)

The next number in the second sequence is

> 16

Reasoning

> Beginning at 4, and moving anti-clockwise, these are the numbers of the white/green segments of a standard [dartboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darts#Dartboard)

Comment: :-) well done - great answer.